# Specify an Android Resource Name for form elements in a Cordova (hybrid) app?

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

As per [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270#signin), I'm attempting to allow Google to complete a pre-launch report on a Cordova hybrid app, but I haven't found how to specify a resource name on a form element. (Nor how to determine what it's being assigned automatically, if it is.)

I wonder whether the below (emphasis mine) means that it's not possible, but would like someone who knows more than me to confirm either way.

> Note: Credentials can only be automatically inserted into Android apps that use standard Android widgets. **Credentials can't be used in apps** that use OpenGL to render custom controls or apps **that use a WebView for a web-based authentication flow**.